# convert a dataframe column of list of dictionaries to multiple columns with dictionary keys as new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one column named `col1`. Each row is a list of dictionaries and the length of them can be different.

| col1 |
| --- |
| [{'id': '35879', 'values': ['fl/li', 'auto'], 'status': []}, {'id': '5056', 'values': ['and'], 'status': []}, {'id': '13431', 'values': ['2'], 'status': []}, {'id': '16102', 'values': ['usb'], 'status': []}, {'id': '4300', 'values': ['13.0'], 'status': ['mp']}, {'id': '12461', 'values': ['core'], 'status': []}, ] |
| [{'id': '35879', 'values': ['fl/li', 'auto'], 'status': []}, {'id': '35879', 'values': ['and'], 'status': []}, {'id': '13430', 'values': ['1080p (hd)', '1080p'], 'status': []}, {'id': '12462', 'values': ['1.3'], 'status': ['gh']}, {'id': '13431', 'values': ['2'], 'status': []},] |
| [{'id': '3555', 'values': ['opt', ], 'status': []}, ] |

I need to convert this to a dataframe with 3 columns similar to the following table and then remove duplicated rows:

| id | values | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35879 | ['fl/li', 'auto'] | [] |
| 5056 | ['and'] | [] |
| 13431 | ['2'] | [] |
| 16102 | ['usb'] | [] |
| ..... | ....... | ... |
| 4300 | ['13.0'] | ['mp'] |
| 12461 | ['core'] | [ts] |
| 35879 | ['fl/li', 'auto'] | [] |
| 3555 | ['opt', ] | [gh] |

I tried many ways and also the following from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282502/convert-list-of-dictionaries-in-a-column-to-multiple-columns-in-same-dataframe)

```
from itertools import chain
s=pd.DataFrame([dict(chain(*map(dict.items, x))) for x in df.pop('col1').tolist()], index=df.index)
```

This will give me a dataframe with 3 columns, but the `values` column only includes the first item of the list. How should I generate the desired dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `DataFrame()`+`explode()`+`drop_duplicates()`:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].explode().tolist()).drop_duplicates(subset=['id'])
```

output of `out`:

```
     id     values                status
0   35879   [fl/li, auto]           []
1   5056    [and]                   []
2   13431   [2]                     []
3   16102   [usb]                   []
4   4300    [13.0]                  [mp]
5   12461   [core]                  []
8   13430   [1080p (hd), 1080p]     []
9   12462   [1.3]                   [gh]
11  3555    [opt]                   []
```